# Android - Screen Event

Tags: android, events, android-activity, back

Can anyone tell me what event is fired when you come from Screen B to Screen A after pressing "BACK" button.

Screen A = 1st screen
Screen B = 2nd screen

what event is fired when i come back to screen A from screen B.

*By Screen i mean Activity

Comment: Both answers posted so far (activity lifecycle methods and onBackPressed) are correct - it depends on where you need to do the processing - in Screen A or Screen B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No "events" are fired, just normal [Activity lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html#Lifecycle) methods are called.

Answer (score 0):

If you actually want to know when you come back from another Activity you have to start Activity B using `startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE)`

And add this method to Activity A:

```
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
         if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {

         } 
 }
```

In Activity B you can use setResult(RESULT_CODE) which you can then rad in onActivityResult using the resultCode.